# Seating 5 boys and 5 girls on 5 two-seat benches

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can you sit 5 boys, and 5 girls on 5  two-seats benches?

I first said that the answer is: $5!*5!*2$ because you can arrange the boys in the right seat, and the girls in the left seat, then the total number of possibilities  is $5!*5!$, then you can switch their seat so my final answer is $5!*5!*2$, but I'm not quite sure about my answer, can someone please tell me the final answer and how to solve it?

Thanks :)

Comment: You may switch seats for each of the 5 benches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sit them in $10!$ different ways.

If you want one bow and one girl on each bench, then you have $2^5$ possibilities to determine which side of the bench is seated by a boy. After you determine that, there are $5!$ possible boy-arrangements, and $5!$ possible girl arangements, making the total 
$$5!\cdot 5!\cdot 2^5$$

Comment: Something interesting: the second case is more restrictive, so $$(5!)^2 \ll 10!$$

This is because the factorial function grows faster than any exponential function (an exponential would satisfy $$f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2=f(x)$$